# How to store AWS access keys in production (and use them in my code)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

If the SDK store is not a good idea, then what is? Is it the configuration file? It would be best if I didn't have to upload the credentials on source control.
The application uses .NET Core.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-access-keys-best-practices.html#iam-user-access-keys

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your application is running on an EC2 instance or using AWS Lambda, then you should not store AWS credentials anywhere.

Instead, you should use IAM Roles to delegate access to your application. The AWS SDKs know how to use credential information through IAM Roles automatically if credentials are not found locally.